# Latexing within iCloud Drive

Tags: macos, latex, sublimetext3, sublimetext, icloud-drive

This is a question relative to these two posts ([this one](https://discussions.apple.com/message/27120898#27120898) and [this one](https://discussions.apple.com/message/28074873#28074873)) found on Apple discussion.

I am using Sublime Text 3 to write and compile my latex documents. It works like a charm when I'm working on a local tex file, but it doesn't work when the file is stored on iCloud Drive: it returns directly an emergency stop. Here is the log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.4.19)  29 APR 2016 23:26
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**"/Users/myname/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/tex/paper-1.tex"

! Emergency stop.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
<*> "/Users/myname/Library/Mobile Documents/com~
                                                 apple~CloudDocs/tex/paper-1...
*** (job aborted, file error in nonstop mode)


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 6 strings out of 493089
 278 string characters out of 6134842
 53199 words of memory out of 5000000
 3590 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 3i,0n,0p,1b,6s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Maybe it is related to the way iCloud automatically organizes the files by type...

Did anyone get rid of this issue?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Is there an error or anything?

Comment: Yes, sorry I've forgot to mention it. I edit the question.

Comment: The issue is that pdflatex cannot handle filenames/paths with tildes in them. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try creating a symlink to the cloud directory, e.g.

```
ln -s ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs Documents/CloudDocs
```

and run the command from `~/Documents/CloudDocs` instead.

Comment: I did not see your answer back at the time, and I stopped using compiling my latex docs from iCloud since then. Your solution actually works well, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, the simplest solution was to configure my iCloud Drive to sync "Desktop & Documents Folders" and then locate my TeX files somewhere within one of these. Then, the default file path (if synced with iCloud) does not include the ~ character.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the other answers, and in case you are using VS Code with LaTeX Workshop, you can solve this issue by going into the settings under "Latex: Tools" and opening the .json file linked. Then replace every instance of `%DOC%` to `%DOCFILE%`, as mentioned in their [wiki](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/wiki/FAQ#path-containing-chinese-or--characters).

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old thread but I just ran into this issue with an \include (or \input) using a regular file name, which is in fact stored in iCloud and thus the name is substituted by Mac OS as a name like /Users/rossiter/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/MyDocs/<something.tex>,
with those ~ in the path name.

As noted above, PDF LaTeX can not deal with these. So I had to move the MyDocs folder back into the regular file system, after deleting the alias I had placed there to point to iCloud.

Maybe this will be useful to someone.